# Unusual behavior from Squid reverse proxy using Cloudflare

Tags: networking, proxy, pfsense, squid, cloudflare

I have installed the Squid proxy on my pfSense instance to direct traffic via URL/host to 4 servers in my local homelab network due to having only one public IP. (to be precise, mail, file/NAS, web, and GitLab servers) I use Cloudflare to protect my site, HTTPS and for the efficient caching/CDN. (free tier) However, on the proxied domains, I get a very peculiar behavior of the proxy rotating addresses/destinations in between the sites even though I am visiting just one domain?

For example, I try to visit my primary site and it starts with my file/asset servers splash page, then on a reload, rotates to a very broken Mailcow sign in screen (the network tab shows the assets needed for the rest of the page send back either a 520 from CF, ERR::CONNECTION_RESET, or 404s from what I presume may be separate or the original servers), then rotates to GitLab being very confused, then to my companies closing page hosted on the web server but it never seems to hit the correct server for the page, no matter how many times I reload. (and get asked by Cloudflare if I am a bot lol)

These behaviors do not exist on unproxied domains. Accessing my unproxied mail server's control panel/webmail conventionally returns normal behavior. This behavior exists after purging the cache, enabling Developer Mode, flushing DNS and browser cache, restarting the proxy, pfSense itself, and the servers affected. The setup with mappings isn't very complicated, HTTPS only, with all domains routed to each server existing on the mapping with no load balancing or anything fancy like that. (I have attempted formats for the URL like `example.com`, `.example.com`, `https://example.com/`, `https://.example.com/`, `^https://example.com/*.$`)

I have been banging my head against a wall with this frankly weird behavior, after ditching HAProxy after it fully refusing to comply with Cloudflare at all. All assistance is appreciated. TIA!

Comment: It'll be hard to assist without seeing squid's configuration. But if you had problems with haproxy too, you may need to have a look at Cloudflare. Haproxy was a better choice, Squid wasn't originally a reverse proxy.

Comment: [Here](https://pastebin.com/nVyFxcY3) is my Squid configuration. I censored my domains and publicly routable IPv6 addresses, obviously, but I hope this can help. I might try using HAProxy again if this doesn't work out. I am using Squid now due to the ease of configuration and tutorial availability, aside from the issues happening now as well. Thanks! 

PS: I have never had these issues with Cloudflare, even on HAProxy, up until now.

Comment: I haven't found an error yet.  cache_peer_access  should be grouped per peer.  What's the use of the "never_direct" lines? Anything useful in the logs?

Comment: pfSense itself specified these rules (see the comment at the top). I will admit, it has a questionable lack of interface options when it comes to fine tuning rules like that, but could it be that severe of an issue? The logs show nothing amiss. The web server logs are about as confusing as the situation at hand.

Comment: One more thing I noticed:  the round-robin options for the cache_peer directives. ???   Are you saying you didn't touch this config yourself?

Comment: That may be it. I haven't touched this config aside from censoring the info when I put it in Pastebin. I'll look in the advanced settings in pfSense to see if I can change that. It's weird because I have them all setup as different ACLs completely. Good eye!

Comment: According to https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/MultipleWebservers, your config can be reduced to 3 lines per backend.  BTW, why the SSL in-house? Afraid the CPU  would get bored?

Comment: I might attempt what they outline in that article, as the pfSense UI has an "advanced settings" section for this kind of thing. However, I might just flat out ditch pfSense over just a Ubuntu Server instance as having these issues over a stubborn UI outweigh the benefits. Also, about the SSL, the UI required it for some reason but I was also using it as a central SSL proxy because some of the software (i.e. Mailcow and GitLab) doesn't like Cloudflare Certbot plugins and have to rely on self signed certificates. Some of the hosts have to be unproxied and CF wont cover the SSL, and cause issues.